# There is an error in this program. Please can anyone identify it? Thanks

Tags: c++

*Hi all there seems to be an error in this program in the sense it is showing wrong output. Rather than showing number of consonants and vowels it is printing the length of the string.*

```
#include<iostream>
  using namespace std;   // program to display the vowels and consonants of a string

   int countvowels(char a[])
 {
    int count =0;
for(int i =0; a[i]!='\0';i++)  
{
    if((a[i]>=65 && a[i]<=90) || (a[i]>=97 && a[i]<=122)) // ignores digits,special characters
    {
        if((a[i]=65) || (a[i]=69) || (a[i]=73) || (a[i]=79) || (a[i]=85) || (a[i]=97) || (a[i]=101) || (a[i]=105) || (a[i]=111)  || (a[i]=117)  ) //ignores consonants
        {
            count++; //counts filtered out vowels 
        }
    }
}
return count;  // returns number of vowels which will be captured by x of main function
}
  int countconsonants(char a[])
{
    int count =0;
for(int i =0; a[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    if((a[i]>=65 && a[i]<=90) || (a[i]>=97 && a[i]<=122))  // ignores digits,special characters
    {
        if((a[i]!=65) || (a[i]!=69) || (a[i]!=73) || (a[i]!=79) || (a[i]!=85) || (a[i]!=97) || (a[i]!=101) || (a[i]!=105) || (a[i]!=111)  ||(a[i]!=117)  ) //ignores vowels
        {
            count++; //counts filtered out consonants
        }
    }
}
return count; // returns number of consonants which will be captured by y of 
 main function
 }

 int main()
 {
 char a[100]; 
 cout<<"Enter the string"<<endl;cin.get(a,100);
 int x = countvowels(a);
  int y = countconsonants(a);

 cout<<"Number of vowels is"<<x<<endl;              //nothing much to say about this part of the program. x just displays it and y does the same
cout<<"Number of consonants is"<<y<<endl;

return 0;
 }
```

Here are the ASCII values of vowels.

1. A , a = 65,97
2. E,e = 69, 101
3. I,i = 73, 105
4. O,o = 79,111
5. U,u = 85,117

Comment: *Fix-my-code* questions are explicitly **off-topic** on SO. So compile your code with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), improve it to get no warnings, and **use the debugger `gdb`** (and perhaps other tools, e.g. `valgrind`).

Comment: You're using `=` instead of `==` in one of your if statements, for one thing

Comment: BTW, you should avoid hard-coding the ASCII encoding of letters.  Today, [UTF-8 is used everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/). So write `'a'`, not 97. Look also some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/). Consider [isalpha](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)

Comment: Use std::string, not char arrays.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Look debugging does help but it doesnt provide reasons on why it is showing an error, which is why i am posting here. I don't understand what made you say that. Look you down voted it, you put my question on hold,  but didnt give a relevant solution. Dont you think your answer is "off topic?". Learn to respond properly to those who seek help.  Also try to be POLITE. It matters alot.

Comment: My comment is a comment, not an answer (otherwise, I would have posted an answer). And the rule of the site is that fix-my-code questions are off-topic. At last, my comments are polite (but short, as every comment should be). What makes you think they are not polite? BTW, I am not a native English speaker (I'm French) so perhaps I am not understanding the nuances you are percieving

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Well SO gets hard on new comers. I am sorry if my prev comment offended you. I wrote this question after thoroughly going through "how to write a question on SO". I am not sure if you had noticed it but i tried writing comments to increase the readability of my question.That's why i felt a bit offended reading such comment(s).  Thanks i shall take this into consideration when i write a question next time. Cheers..

Comment: Debugging is a *human* activity requiring intelligence (read about the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)) that cannot be entirely automated. The [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) is a useful tool for you to understand the behavior of your program. But you (not us) need to understand what is happening in it. And SO is not a *do-my-homework* service neither.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch This isnt a hw question.... Why do people keep saying that. One more thing. I just wanted to know where i went wrong.Thats the first thing in learning something new. This isnt a do-my-homework question.. And again, thanks for sharing that info.

Comment: If you are learning to program alone read http://norvig.com/21-days.html and [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). IMNSHO C++ is a very difficult programming language, not the best one to learn programming from scratch. But consider also reading http://stroustrup.com/Programming/

Comment: BTW, learning to program is not (mostly) learning a programming language (but is a lot more about learning to *design*, to *understand* and to *debug* programs). So asking what is wrong in your program is certainly useless. You need to find out by yourself (otherwise you are *not* programming). In other words [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) is much more important than [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems with your code:

1. In checking for equality. To check if two value are equal you should use double equals`==` instead of a single equals. A single equal sign will mean assignment not equality check
2. In logical condition in count_consonants. `a != 1 || a != 2` will always evaluate to true